# lines linear model ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the lines thicker without adding geom_line

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=c, y=d, colour=group)) +
      geom_point()+
      geom_smooth( method=lm,se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I assume you mean "thicker". Did you try adding `size=...` in the call to `geom_smooth(...)`.